# Performance Comparisons between Series and Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am building a Performance comparison Table between Numpy and Series:

Two Instances caught my Eye. Any help will be really helpful.

1. We say that we should avoid using Loops in Numpy and Series, but I came across one scenario where for loop is performing better

In Below Code I am Calculating Density of Planets using for Loops and without for Loop

```
mass=  pd.Series([0.330, 4.87, 5.97, 0.073, 0.642, 1898, 568, 86.8, 102, 0.0146], index = ['MERCURY', 'VENUS', 'EARTH', 'MOON', 'MARS', 'JUPITER', 'SATURN', 'URANUS', 'NEPTUNE', 'PLUTO'])
diameter = pd.Series([4879, 12104, 12756, 3475, 6792, 142984, 120536, 51118, 49528, 2370], index = ['MERCURY', 'VENUS', 'EARTH', 'MOON', 'MARS', 'JUPITER', 'SATURN', 'URANUS', 'NEPTUNE', 'PLUTO'])
 
%%timeit -n 1000
 
density = mass / (np.pi * np.power(diameter, 3) /6)
 
1000 loops, best of 3: 617 µs per loop
 
%%timeit -n 1000
 
density = pd.Series()

for planet in mass.index:

    density[planet] = mass[planet] / ((np.pi * np.power(diameter[planet], 3)) / 6)
 
1000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop
```

2. Second, I am trying to replace nan values in Series using Two approaches

Why do the First approach works Faster??? My Guess is that second approach is converting Series Object in N-d array

```
sample2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4325, 23, 3, 4213, 102, 89, 4, np.nan, 6, 803, 43, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
 
x = np.mean(sample2)
 
x
 
%%timeit -n 10000
 
sample3 = pd.Series(np.where(np.isnan(sample2), x, sample2))
 
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
 
%%timeit -n 10000
 
sample2[np.isnan(sample2)] =x
 
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the result of the first part; the `for` loop is about 15x **slower** than the vectorized approach (perhaps try clearing the kernel before benchmarking?). For the second part, I see three method (`np.where`, `np.isnan`, `pd.isnull`), among which the second is the slowest, as opposed to your question. Can you make them a bit clearer?

Comment: I tried on my system, and the first approach (`density = mass / (np.pi * np.power(diameter, 3) /6)`) is much faster: `1000 loops, best of 3: 278 µs per loop` vs `1000 loops, best of 3: 4.55 ms per loop` (notice microseconds vs milliseconds).

Comment: @Chris.. Sorry for that.. I have modified my question so that it makes a clear sense ..

Answer (score 0):

In an `ipython` console session:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: mass=  pd.Series([0.330, 4.87, 5.97, 0.073, 0.642, 1898, 568, 86.8, 102, 0.
   ...: 0146], index = ['MERCURY', 'VENUS', 'EARTH', 'MOON', 'MARS', 'JUPITER', 'SA
   ...: TURN', 'URANUS', 'NEPTUNE', 'PLUTO'])
   ...: diameter = pd.Series([4879, 12104, 12756, 3475, 6792, 142984, 120536, 51118
   ...: , 49528, 2370], index = ['MERCURY', 'VENUS', 'EARTH', 'MOON', 'MARS', 'JUPI
   ...: TER', 'SATURN', 'URANUS', 'NEPTUNE', 'PLUTO'])
   ...: 
In [3]: mass
Out[3]: 
MERCURY       0.3300
VENUS         4.8700
EARTH         5.9700
MOON          0.0730
MARS          0.6420
JUPITER    1898.0000
SATURN      568.0000
URANUS       86.8000
NEPTUNE     102.0000
PLUTO         0.0146
dtype: float64
In [4]: diameter
Out[4]: 
MERCURY      4879
VENUS       12104
EARTH       12756
MOON         3475
MARS         6792
JUPITER    142984
SATURN     120536
URANUS      51118
NEPTUNE     49528
PLUTO        2370
dtype: int64
```

Your density calculation creates a Series with the same index.  Here the index of the Series match, but I think in general `pandas` is able to match up indices.

```
In [5]: density = mass / (np.pi * np.power(diameter, 3) /6)
In [6]: density
Out[6]: 
MERCURY    5.426538e-12
VENUS      5.244977e-12
EARTH      5.493286e-12
MOON       3.322460e-12
MARS       3.913302e-12
JUPITER    1.240039e-12
SATURN     6.194402e-13
URANUS     1.241079e-12
NEPTUNE    1.603427e-12
PLUTO      2.094639e-12
dtype: float64
In [7]: timeit density = mass / (np.pi * np.power(diameter, 3) /6)
532 µs ± 437 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Since indices match, we can get the same numbers by using the `numpy` values arrays:

```
In [8]: mass.values/(np.pi * np.power(diameter.values, 3)/6)
Out[8]: 
array([5.42653818e-12, 5.24497707e-12, 5.49328558e-12, 3.32246038e-12,
       3.91330208e-12, 1.24003876e-12, 6.19440202e-13, 1.24107933e-12,
       1.60342694e-12, 2.09463905e-12])
In [9]: timeit mass.values/(np.pi * np.power(diameter.values, 3)/6)
11.5 µs ± 67.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

This is much faster.  `numpy` isn't taking time to match indices.  Also it isn't making a new Series.

Your iteration approach:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: density = pd.Series(dtype=float)
    ...: for planet in mass.index:
    ...:     density[planet] = mass[planet] / ((np.pi * np.power(diameter[planet],
    ...: 3)) / 6)
    ...: 

7.36 ms ± 312 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This is much slower.

Out of curiosity, lets initial a Series and fill it with the `numpy` calc:

```
In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: density = pd.Series(index=mass.index, dtype=float)
    ...: density[:] = mass.values/(np.pi * np.power(diameter.values, 3)/6)
241 µs ± 8.97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

2x better than [7], but still quite a bit slower than pure `numpy`.  While `pandas` uses `numpy` arrays - here I think both `index` and `values` are arrays. But `pandas` does add a significant overhead, relative to pure `numpy` code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such Detailed Explanation. Appreciated..